# Запрос к HTTP API Яндекс Карт.Как получить координаты полигона?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Хочу получить координаты муниципального района одного региона. Делаю запрос к HTTP API Яндекс Карт. Но в ответе есть только координаты точки, куда указывает метка на самой карте, но сами координаты всего полигона (района) я найти не могу. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

В настоящее время возможности получать от API Яндекс.Карт границы уровня меньше, чем [регионы](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/regions.html/?from=club), нет.

Поэтому скачивать контуры интересующих вас границ придётся на сторонних сервисах, например http://data.esosedi.org